# python string parsing using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Given a string `#abcde#jfdkjfd`, how can I get the string between two `#` ? And I also want that if no `#` pair(means no `#` or only one `#`), the function will return `None`.

Comment: It seems you can achieve this with a basic regular expression. Have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "abc#def#ghi#jkl"
>>> re.findall(r"(?<=#)[^#]+(?=#)", s)
['def', 'ghi']
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=#)  # Assert that the previous character is a #
[^#]+   # Match 1 or more non-# characters
(?=#)   # Assert that the next character is a #
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `(?<=#)(\w+)(?=#)` and capture the first group. You can even cycle through a string which contains several embedded strings and it will work.

This uses both a positive lookbehind and positive lookahead.

Comment: You don't need a group at all since the lookarounds aren't part of the match.

Comment: Yes, that's true... Just a habit!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't insist on regular expressions and are willing to accept an empty list instead of `None` for the case where there are no results then the easy way is:

```
>>> "#abcde#jfdkjfd".split('#')[1:-1]
['abcde']
```

Note that the result really has to be a list as you could have more than one result.

If you insist on getting `None` instead of an empty list (though not perfect as this would also turn any empty string into None):

```
>>> "#abcde#jfdkjfd".split('#')[1:-1] or None
['abcde']
```

If you only wanted the first marked string then you could do this:

```
>>> def first_marked(s):
    token = s.split('#')
    if len(token) >= 3:
        return token[1]
    else:
        return None


>>> first_marked("#abcde#jfdkjfd")
'abcde'
```